# canot execute this T-SQL function

Tags: t-sql

Cannot execute this function, I am getting the error:

> Must declare the table variable "@Handle".

Function definition:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FnGetHandle]()
RETURNS INT
AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @Handle AS INT;
      DECLARE @strUser AS NCHAR(256);

      SET @Handle = 0;
      SET @strUser = CURRENT_USER;

      INSERT INTO tbl_handle
      Output      Handle
      INTO @Handle ( UserName )
      VALUES      ( @strUser );

      RETURN @Handle
  END
```

Table definition:

> tbl_handle definition (Handle int identity, username nvarchar, created
>   date)

Answer (score 3):

The `output` command outputs to a table or a table variable. You can create a table variable that holds the output value.

```
declare @T table(handle int)

insert into ...
select ...
output inserted.Handle into @T

select @Handle = handle
from @T

return @Handle
```